# excel like application in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an HTML/Javascript application with can behave like an excel sheet. I'm not talking about opening an excel sheet in HTML form but instead creating HTML/javascript code that will behave like an excel sheet where the grids and all will be html code etc. I hope you got my question.

Any ideas as how I can approach this task.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: Hi, could I ask how comprehensive you'd want this to be? Would you want programmatic adding of cells, the ability to export to json or xml, will it need to communicate with a server-side language for saving or anything? What you're asking for is pretty complex, I'm sure the guys at Google would agree (http://docs.google.com/)

Comment: Let's see: javascript, table cells, back end database, validation, cross browser compatibility, AJAX autofills, cell formatting, table resizing, or...

ExtJs

Comment: @Mike Robinson I agree that ExtJS is a great solution, but would still like to know the scope of the project: it may be that a much simpler solution is required and ExtJS is overkill.

Comment: Yeah, it wont be very complicated, I still don't know the complete specs, but what I know, it should have things like Saving data to DB, Exporting to an excel, adding columns, hiding columns, sorting, adding rows, subtotal.

Comment: Out of the box, ExtJS allows a user to hide columns and sort.  Adding rows and subtotals are easy and examples available.

Comment: Can you point me to the example you are talking about. Thanks.

Comment: Start with revogrid, it’s very fast solution with high performance https://github.com/revolist/revogrid

Answer (score 10):

I needed JavaScript data grid with copy/paste compatibility with Excel. I could not find such, so I created jQuery plugin: http://handsontable.com/

Maybe you will find it useful.

Comment: should be mentioned that now this is quite a costy solution, definitely not for Open Source projects. Although I've seen handsontable once and it looked great, copy/paste functionality is very useful

Comment: ah, ok, I probably have to appologize, there's a repository for "community edition" (https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable) which seems to be FOSS (but I'm not sure, haven't found a licence yet); it's just not clear from the main site that there's such edition, found only because tried to search through GitHub

Comment: A very simple and light API: http://bossanova.uk/jexcel

Answer (score 4):

You can do it from scratch or either use this online tool called [Appizy](http://appizy.com). It transforms an OpenOffice sheets into the HTML equivalent table. Basic formulas are transformed into Javascript. It could be a good start for your project.

Only drawback, webpage is in french. Hope it hepls.

Comment: You should mention you are related to this webpage, you did not just stumble upon it...

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you investigate the [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/) grid.  I think it would be a great place to start - a framework for the additional capabilities you are looking to add.

Comment: If you want to pay money.  Else find something better.

Comment: answer should provide `investigations` and `findings`, not just ask to `investigate`.

Answer (score 1):

I would start from two libraries:

- [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) for the grid user interface (very fast, clean codebase)
- [Formula.js](http://stoic.com/formula/) for evaluating formulas (will be released soon)

Comment: now this is the most maintained fork of SlickGrid (I'd say a successor): https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a simple table with text boxes within the td's as far as layout is concerned.  Jquery could be used to attach click handlers to each one for the purpose of handling totalling, and other formulas

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer, but you can have a look to: jqGrid which just need the Jquery which is quite smaller than extJS.

- Doc : http://www.trirand.com/blog/
- Demo at: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
- JQuery: http://jquery.com/