# Excel-like grid in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I would need a blank Excel-like grid inside an html page where the user can copy-paste his values and later push kind of a "submit" button.
I do not know how to construct such a grid (it would be better if I could define headers so the user would know where to add his values).

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not start with a table?

Comment: Either use a table and develop the code on your own or use one of the numerous UI frameworks that come with a grid or table widget. How much of Excel functionality do you need to be replicated (eg. free expansion of size, cell formatting, etc.) ? You need to be more specific and should show some own thoughts or work on the task.

Comment: Are the values just to be numbers or could there be text or other input of any length? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are right guys, I will modify my question and be more specific as soon as I can

Comment: Why dont you use a plugin/library [like this one](https://jspreadsheet.com/home?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIot6vhMu59wIVLpFmAh3UzgN9EAAYASAAEgKFkPD_BwE)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [excel like application in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185636/excel-like-application-in-javascript)